# PHP interface for kernel's IP routing tables

Tags: php, linux, shell, routes, shell-exec

I'm trying to implement a CRUD interface for the IP routing tables and I'm stuck at executing unix commands with PHP.
I've tried to echo the output for the route command using shell_exec command but the output is null.

```
echo shell_exec("route"); // Outputs nothing
```

I've also tried several other combinations like:

```
echo exec("route"); // also outputs nothing
// and
$lastLine = system("route", $output);
echo $lastLine; // nothing
echo $output; // 127
```

So, how should I execute the route command from PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: Whilst resisting the urge to comment on your choice of programming languages, might I suggest using the newer `ip` tools (part of `iproute` or `iproute2`) instead the older `route` command. E.g.: `ip route show` prints your routing table. `ip route help` for more info. It's (A) far more capable, and (B) easier to parse.

Comment: Also -- error 127 is the standard return for when the program you tried to run wasn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first from console

```
whereis route
```

Then execute `route` command with full path

Basically, i think, it because of `PATH` env is not include `/sbin:`

Comment: This solved my problem. By using shell_exec("/sbin/route"); I'm getting what I expect. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just try

```
$outPrint = `route` // not simple quotes!;
echo $outPrint;
```

P.S.: "`" - this is tilde symbol. Console key in more games :)

Comment: Use of the backtick operator is identical to shell_exec(), and he is already try this. See http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php